# C# MongoDB - Pull an item from a nested document's array based on an ID

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, bson

We've been struggling for hours on a query that seems easy to us and that we made through Robo 3T... The issue is now to convert it into C# and we just can't find the way and we don't even understand why it doesn't work.

We have the following query:

```
db.getCollection('UserCollection').update({"User.Contacts._id": ObjectId("xxx")}, 
{
    $pull: {
        "User.Contacts": {
           "_id": {$in:[ObjectId("xxx")]}
    }
  }
})
```

Now that our query works, we try to translate it in c# and we reached that point so far and we don't really know where the issue can come from..

```
public Task PullSocialInfoAsync(ObjectId contactId)
{
    var fieldName = nameof(UserContainer.User) + "." + nameof(UserContainer.User.Contacts) + "._id";
    var filter = NewFilterBuilder().Eq(fieldName, contactId);
    var update = new BsonDocument("$pull", new BsonDocument(nameof(UserContainer.User) + "." + nameof(UserContainer.User.Contacts), new BsonDocument("_id", new BsonDocument("$in", new BsonArray() { contactId }))));
    return GetCurrentCollection().FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);
}
```

Here you see `FindOneAndUpdateAsync`, but we tried we `UpdateAsync` as well, also we change multiple time the initialisation of our BsonArray with no success, even if the query as string match what we have on Robo 3T

Based on the above C# query, we have that output:
`{{ "$pull" : { "User.Contacts" : { "_id" : { "$in" : [ObjectId("xxx")] } } } }}`. The most interesting part is that if I copy paste.. well it works

Any ideas?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

if i understood your requirement correctly, a `pullFilter` is what you need.

```cs
var filter = Builders<UserCollection>.Filter.Where(u => u.User.Contacts.Any(c => c._Id == contactID));
var update = Builders<UserCollection>.Update.PullFilter(u => u.User.Contacts, c => c._Id == contactID);
collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

here's the full program for testing if anybody's interested.

```js
using MongoDB.Entities; // PM> Install-Package MongoDB.Entities
using MongoDB.Bson;    
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class UserCollection : Entity
        {
            public User User { get; set; }
        }

        public class User
        {
            public Contact[] Contacts { get; set; }
        }

        public class Contact
        {
            public ObjectId _Id { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            var contactID = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();

            (new UserCollection
            {
                User = new User
                {
                    Contacts = new[]
                    {
                        new Contact { _Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId()},
                        new Contact { _Id = contactID}
                    }
                }
            }).Save();

            DB.Update<UserCollection>()
              .Match(u => u.User.Contacts.Any(c => c._Id == contactID))
              .Modify(b => b.PullFilter(u => u.User.Contacts, c => c._Id == contactID))
              .Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I couldn't check yet but your approach seems to look like EntityFramework which is totally different from mine soo I will look into it :)

Comment: if you have c# classes that mirror the mongodb documents, then you can use lambda expressions to refer to the fields/properties for strong-typing and not use bsondocuments or magic strings like i've shown. you can ignore the code inside the snippet if you want a pure official driver solution. cheers!